# Why this function composition is illegal

Tags: haskell, syntax

This works:

```
c <- fmap lines (readFile "d:\\tmp\\h.txt")  
let h = map (read :: String -> Int) c
```

while "superposition" of those two lines those not compile

`fmap (read :: String -> Int) $ fmap lines (readFile "d:\\tmp\\h.txt")`

it generates error:

```
interactive:1:36:
    Couldn't match expected type `Char' with actual type `[Char]'
    Expected type: String -> String
      Actual type: String -> [String]
    In the first argument of `fmap', namely `lines'
    In the second argument of `($)', namely
      `fmap lines (readFile "d:\\tmp\\h.txt")
```

Why it does not compile and how to do this in one line? What I want is achieve a simplicity of python

```
[int(i) for i in open("d:\\tmp\\h.txt")]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You left the `map` out of your "superposition" (composition):

```
h <- fmap (map (read :: String -> Int)) $ fmap lines (readFile "d:\\tmp\\h.txt")
```

You can simplify that to

```
h <- fmap (map (read :: String -> Int) . lines) (readFile "d:\\tmp\\h.txt")
```

If you put an `import Control.Applicative` line at the top of your source file (or enter `:m +Control.Applicative` if you're using ghci interactively), you can use the `<$>` operator instead of `fmap` to make it look cleaner. (They do exactly the same thing, they're just spelled differently.)

```
h <- map (read :: String -> Int) . lines <$> readFile "d:\\tmp\\h.txt"
```

Finally, if you do need the type signature, you might find it looks clearer at the end of the line.

```
h <- map read . lines <$> readFile "d:\\tmp\\h.txt" :: IO [Int]
```

Comment: Also, I'd move that `read` to where/let binding, `fmap (map readInt . lines) $ readFile "foo"` is far more readable IMO.

Answer (score 9):

```
[int(i) for i in open("d:\\tmp\\h.txt")]
```

Keep computation separate from actions:

```
return . map read . lines =<< readFile "d:\\tmp\\h.txt"
```

Comment: The hlint in my brain sees `foo >>= return . bar` and tells me to transform it to `bar <$> foo`

Answer (score 9):

re. your second question: using `Applicative` would make it more readable:

```
map read . lines <$> readFile "file"
```

You may be able to avoid giving `read` a type signature, depending on the rest of your code, which would be preferable

Comment: n.b. The OP needs to `import Control.Applicative` to use the `<$>` operator.